# Instance a plane on a cylinder using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Using a cylinder with a couple of loop cuts added

[image: base geometry]

I just add a plane and then point instance this on the vertices of the cylinder. Can I make the planes attach to the faces instead of the vertices? How would you rotate the planes so they look like they are on the surface of the cylinder?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a [Point Distribute](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/point/point_distribute.html) node to instance on faces rather than vertices. The instanced geometry is automatically facing the face normal.

[image]

[image]

If you want to instance a plane on the center of each face, you can use a little trick with the [Edge Split](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/edge_split.html) and [Smooth](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/smooth.html) modifiers.

Set the *Edge split* angle to 0° so all faces are disconnected, then use a low value around 1.1 for the *Smooth* factor. Increase the repeat until faces are really small. Add the GN modifier afterwards.

[image]

Using the *Poisson Disk* distribution on the Point Distribute node, set the Density to a very high value, and tweak the distance so only 1 plane is instanced on each face. It's best to tweak the distance first so as not to crash Blender with a gazillion instances :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you also know how this works without point distribute? because i never got this running...?

Comment: @Chris I think it's the only way to distribute points on faces... What part didn't work out ?

Comment: The rotation of the planes if you don‘t use the distributed points node

Comment: @Chris Try that https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsGai.png

Comment: you are my hero!!! works like a charm!!

Comment: Yikes. 1. a lot of jumping-through-hoops 2. Computational inefficiency. Grateful as we might be, GN has a long way to go, yet.

Comment: @RobinBetts my thoughts exactly, not intuitive to be using point distribute then basically hack things to get what you want. But its a great start and will only get better.