# How to create instances in the centers of faces or edges, instead of on verts?

Tags: geometry-nodes

This is what the `Point Instance` node creates by default:

[image: Instances created on verts]

Is there a way to create the points in the centers of the faces?

[image: Instances created on faces]

Or in the center of edges?

[image: Instances created on edges]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Instance a plane on a cylinder using geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227681/instance-a-plane-on-a-cylinder-using-geometry-nodes)

Comment: @Luciano No, I've found the solution (see answer below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out: use the subdivide node. That'll create verts in the centers of existing faces and edges. From there you just have to mask out the points you want to instance.

Node tree:
[image: solution]

Result:
[image: Instanced objects on verts, edges, and faces]

The only problem is that the objects don't rotate to match the angle of the edge/face if the mesh is deformed (but they DO maintain their outward angle).

[image: rotaion problem]

I guess you can't have everything...

Comment: This is clever ! Pretty reliable to get edge center points, although with faces with more than 4 verts it can get a little messy to output the face center. I think you can indeed extract the face normal and use that to orient the objects. You may have to use attribute transfer node from 3.0 to do that though