# Geometry node - instantiating a cube only in the middle of another geometry edge

Tags: instances, geometry-nodes

I would like to instantiate a cube in the middle of an edge of an ico sphere.

[image]

I'm thinking about converting to a curve, subdividing it and then make a mask between the primitive sphere and the subdivided sphere, but I'm stuck on how to do this.

I found the post *[How to create instances in the centers of faces or edges, instead of on verts?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/230701/how-to-create-instances-in-the-centers-of-faces-or-edges-instead-of-on-verts)*, but it was done with the legacy version of the geometry nodes.

Comment: What is an *"ico sphere"*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just a follow-up to the commentary on [@possibly ferret's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/263953/35559). You can instance directly on the edges of  a mesh, and set the rotation, too..

[image]

.. here, in 2 stages: 1. around 'Auto' to put Z on the normal, 2. around the (now good) 'Z' to put Y down the edge.

[image]

Comment: this is briliant

Answer (score 7):

You could convert the mesh to curves, then subdivide, and with the node `Endpoint Selection` select the middle points and instantiate there.

[image]

If you also want to transfer the rotation from the edges to the instantiated cubes, you can capture the selection of the middle points with the node `Capture Attribute`.

In order to align the cubes correctly, you would first have to capture the normals of the faces and combine it with the rotation you get from the `Curve to Points` node.
You can then pass the resulting rotation directly to the `Instance on Points` node.

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot for quick and detailled answer!

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do it, is by using a *mesh to points* set to edges:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's right, this is technically the easiest way to find the center point, but the rotation unfortunately makes no sense at all here because of the missing tangents/normals.

Comment: yes that's true, unfortunately you will still need to do the curve tangent method to achieve that