# align instance average between 2 faces

Tags: geometry-nodes

I need to rotate the object around its center to align to the average between the 2 faces on either side. I found this answer which is absolutely what I want to do but to no avail. Really I need is a flat side pointing up (not the corner)

This is exactly what I want to achieve but can not find the correct solution
[Geometry node - instantiating a cube only in the middle of another geometry edge](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/263942/geometry-node-instantiating-a-cube-only-in-the-middle-of-another-geometry-edge)

[image]

[image: Flat sides need to face up]

Comment: pls consider to accept answers, if they helped you, by clicking on the checkmark left to that answers. This shows others that the answer is helpful and makes the site more useful. thx.

Answer (score 5):

you can try this node setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily the right way for you to go... (this illustration leaves out other aspects, scaling by edge-length, etc.,) ... but if your reference geometry has faces,  a *Normal* in the Edge domain is the average of the normals of adjacent faces.

[image]